# How to convert a percentage to a decimal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So here is an example of my code:

```
var = int(input("What is your restaurant bill: "))
var2 = int(input("How much percent did you tip(Don't add the % symbol)? "))
```

I want this to print the percentage increase plus the total. Here is an example:

```
#input
var = 50
var2 = 5
#output
50*1.05 = 52.5
```

So in this example, how would I convert the 5% to 1.05?

Comment: just `1 + var2/100`

Comment: Why is it `100*1.05` instead of `50*1.05`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unrelated to programming. Should get posted in https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Since var2 shows us the percentage of the tip in probability 1 represents 100% hence var2/100 would show the % out of 1. Now add 1 ( or 100% in our case) to var2/100